# mounting a pseudo-tty in a docker container

Tags: docker, tty

My docker container has a script that opens a serial connection to a real TTY device in the production environment, something like an Arduino.  For local testing without real connected devices, I would like to create an emulated TTY and then run the same docker container pointed at this pseudo-tty.  When I create the pseudo-tty and run `docker run --device=/dev/pts/2 test` I get the error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:65: creating device nodes caused \\\"open /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/242a13eadb75e802b2eab8dc01c701c4ad671195b93f7b956000f32ac0911e24/dev/pts/2: permission denied\\\"\"".`

If I run with `--privileged` and connect into the running container, the path is not present in `/dev/pts`.  My host is a Debian jessie instance.

Is there a way to connect to this pseudo-tty from inside the container?  Or is there a better way to do this testing that comes to mind?

Comment: Using `--privileged`, you may be able to just `--volume /dev/pts:/dev/pts`.

Comment: Does `-t` in `docker run -t` work for you?

Comment: Long time ago @Matt, but did you come to a solution? Mind posting an answer?

Comment: @panepeter our stack uses the method from @larsks above without `--privileged` and with in the context of docker-compose, hth!